# I ask for help in areas I don't know when I study programming linguistics

Tags: c, theory

I am a college student studying programming linguistics. I posted a similar question a while ago, but I mispublished it, and I have a similar question, so I ask for your help.

Questions are as follows.

For an elementary data type in a language with which you are familiar, do the following:

- Explain the difference between data objects of that type and the values that those data objects may contain.

In this textbook, data object means the memory location that contains the data value. And Value is one of the attributes of the data object.

What I don't understand is how to compare two concepts, not the same class, with value, one of the attributes of data objects, and data objects, which are its top concepts.

I tried to understand it in various ways, but I couldn't understand it, so I asked for your help. Thank you.

I was solving the problem by setting the language that I am familiar with as C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this question is the following:

- The data object is a specific physical instance of storage for a value of the type. This physical instance exists in a definite time and the value it contains may change over time. There was a time before it existed and there will be a time when it is gone - maybe temporarily but eventually forever. Two data objects that hold the same value are nevertheless distinct in that they have separate existence.
- The value is a nonphysical general principle which is a member of some theoretical set of possible values. The general principal does not exist in time or space but can be thought of as existing in the "Platonic universe of ideal forms"; it is an idea. In a sense, the idea of the value has always existed - before mankind discovered it - and will continue on after mankind is gone. There is no such thing as two distinct values that are the same; if you see two values that are the same, it's actually the same value; there's just one number 2, no matter in what context or how many times you see it used.

In C, the data objects of primitive type `int` are at-least-16-bit storage buckets for values between (at a minimum range) -2^16 and 2^16-1. Consider this code snippet:

```
int n1 = 2;
int n2 = 2;
```

In this code snippet, we have two data objects - `n1` and `n2` - but just one value - `2`.